# Hide element or keep same size on smarthphone zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed header (bootstrap nav bar), that keeps resizing with rest of page, which results in header taking half screen space on smartphones.

```
%header{class: 'navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse'}
  .container
#sorry for haml
```

I want to either hide header when user zooms in or just keep it same size no matter how much screen is zoomed in.

No idea if that changes anything but I am using bootstrap.
I found a class `.hidden-xs-down` but it hides header even when page is not zoomed in, so that's not quite it.

Most of things I have found is about resizing window on big screens and some things happening when it reaches xs,md,lg threshold. What I need is to detect when user zooms in (resize) xs smarthphone screen.

Hope you understand what I mean.

So, any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer in a precise way without knowing more details of your header element (is it an `h2` element? An image?)  But in a general way, here is a technique you can use to hide something for screens narrower than a certain width:

```
.my-header { display: none; }
@media(min-width: 500px) {
  .my-header { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: It's a fixed navigation element - nav bar. Problem with your answer is that I don't want to hide it on smaller screens (let's say 3.5 inch screen should still display it). I want to hide it only when it's being resized (zoomed).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I want to do the same thing add a class to element hide it if the user zooms on mobile??